# MySQL get latest 20 product order by price

Tags: mysql

I have to get 20 latest products ordered by price.
I am using this query.

```
SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY created_at DESC, price ASC LIMIT 20
```

Comment: Your query looks fine. You are getting any error?

Comment: I am not getting correct results. it is just ordering by time not by price

Comment: Its ordering them foremost by time and then by price. Change the order of `created_at` and `price`

Comment: then it shows olders records also which has higher prices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

u can try self-join

```
SELECT p1.* FROM products AS p1 
INNER JOIN
     (SELECT id
     FROM products
     ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 20) AS p2
ON p1.id = p2.id
ORDER BY p1.price ASC
```

Im not sure about joining to temporary tables in laravel query-builder. 
At least u can do this in raw-way:

```
$results = DB::select(DB::raw("
    SELECT p1.* FROM products AS p1 
    INNER JOIN
            (SELECT id
            FROM products
            ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 20) AS p2
        ON p1.id = p2.id
    ORDER BY p1.price ASC
"));
```

Comment: It will work, but dont you think it will decrease performance ?

Comment: I am getting this error.
Syntax error or access violation: 1235 This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'

Comment: about perfomance.. its ok, if id is a key. btw there is no other ("faster") way to do what you want. you can also make created_ad an index